# Where is the location of "velocity.log" for aTomcat deployment of a Vaadin/Apache Cayenne app?

Tags: java, tomcat, vaadin, velocity, apache-cayenne

I'm deploying an app which uses Vaadin and Apache Cayenne. It is causing a problem as I deploy it on Tomcat running as user "www". (If I run Tomcat as "root' there is no problem.)

It complains that there is a no permission to access/write a file called "velocity.log". Does anyone know where is the location Cayenne/Tomcat is accessing the file?

I tried to find out by:

```
File file = new File("test");
String testPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println(testPath );
```

and I saw that it prints out "/config". I therefore tried to create a directory and setting the right permissions from root "/config" and I've also tried doing the same at several locations within the Tomcat directory. None worked.

It is running now within Tomcat because I set the user to "root". I'd like to set it back to "www" but I need to resolve this problem first. Does anyone know where is location for the supposedly "velocity.log" file in a Tomcat deployment?

Comment: What folder you start the tomcat ?

Comment: While Cayenne up till and including 4.0 has a hard dependency on Velocity library, it also suppresses velocity.log file generation: https://github.com/apache/cayenne/blob/STABLE-4.0/cayenne-server/src/main/java/org/apache/cayenne/velocity/VelocitySQLTemplateProcessor.java#L104 Are you using / reconfiguring Velocity outside Cayenne? Also which version of Cayenne are you using?

Comment: Did you find your log file ? tomcat/bin folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Notice Apache Cayenne is using Velocity 1.6 which is not 2.0 (different logging settings),

[Velocity Logging](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/developer-guide.html#configuring-logging) will create the file on your folder where to "started" it, in your case in the **folder you execute** Tomcat (check your script you are running)

> Velocity will setup a file-based logger that will output all logging
>   messages to a file called velocity.log in the 'current directory'
>   where Velocity was initialized.